# Connect SQL server through azure active directory integrated authentication from local Java code

Tags: java, sql, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

My SQL database is in Azure. it has only azure active directory-integrated authentication. I have Java code in my local machine. I want extract data from SQL db through the Java code. How will I authenticate my Java code to get access to SQL DATABASE?

A sample Java code or procedure to connect to SQL db through azure active directory integrated authentication.

Comment: _SQL server_ - as in MS SQL Server?

Comment: Coud you please provide your approach and error if you have tried anything?

Comment: I think they were intending to write "MySQL" but added a space? Not completely sure here. Maybe they can clarify?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect an Azure SQL database with **Active Directory Integrated** authentication,

> you must [federate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/connect/whatis-fed) the on-premises Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) with Microsoft Entra ID in the cloud.

I suggest you try using **Active Directory Interactive Authentication** instead of Active Directory Integrated Authentication.

You can use the code below:

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource;

public class MSEntraInteractive {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
        ds.setServerName("<serverName>.database.windows.net");
        ds.setDatabaseName("<databaseName>");
        ds.setAuthentication("ActiveDirectoryInteractive");
        ds.setUser("<userName>");
        try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
             Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUSER_SNAME()")) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("You have successfully logged on as: " + rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will connect to the database successfully. For more information, refer to this [MS document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#using-interactive-authentication).